# 200 + GenerateDSYMFile warnings in xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, xcode7

After updating some of my 3rd party SDK's (Facebook Audience Network  + others) I am experiencing tons of these types of warnings when I build.

```
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/stakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Weather_-haqumjcbppvcpwareowgymfxekqg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Weather\ .app.dSYM /Users/stakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Weather_-haqumjcbppvcpwareowgymfxekqg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Weather\ .app/Weather\ 
            cd /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps
            export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/stakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Weather_-haqumjcbppvcpwareowgymfxekqg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Weather\ .app/Weather\  -o /Users/stakhar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Weather_-haqumjcbppvcpwareowgymfxekqg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Weather\ .app.dSYM

        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/Darwin-MI6WZSG1PNOM.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/Darwin-MI6WZSG1PNOM.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/AudioToolbox-IDGAMJDSP9Z1.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/AudioToolbox-IDGAMJDSP9Z1.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/CoreMedia-GG7O0RHFFJKF.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/CoreMedia-GG7O0RHFFJKF.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/QuartzCore-3I7S0M4UEAD0U.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/QuartzCore-3I7S0M4UEAD0U.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/SystemConfiguration-2O070L5BFB5B1.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/SystemConfiguration-2O070L5BFB5B1.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/StoreKit-2XFSXANXKLC2A.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCache.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/StoreKit-2XFSXANXKLC2A.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/StoreKit-2XFSXANXKLC2A.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/StoreKit-2XFSXANXKLC2A.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/Darwin-MI6WZSG1PNOM.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/Darwin-MI6WZSG1PNOM.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/AudioToolbox-IDGAMJDSP9Z1.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/AudioToolbox-IDGAMJDSP9Z1.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/CoreMedia-GG7O0RHFFJKF.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/CoreMedia-GG7O0RHFFJKF.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/QuartzCore-3I7S0M4UEAD0U.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/QuartzCore-3I7S0M4UEAD0U.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/SystemConfiguration-2O070L5BFB5B1.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/SystemConfiguration-2O070L5BFB5B1.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No such file or directory
        while processing /Users/stakhar/Dropbox/WeatherApps/development/iOS/WeatherApps/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdCommandProcessor.o):
        warning: /var/folders/9j/vw2bf7xn53g9ms_nnp0sct9167gh9d/C/org.llvm.clang.chrisp/ModuleCache/1G1JKM0ZTO8SX/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
```

After researching this problem I discovered that there were some adjustments that can be made to build settings that has resolved the problem for some people:

- Precompile Prefix (GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER) = NO
- Debug Information Format (DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT) = DWARF with dSYM
- Enabled Modules (C and Objective-C) (CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES) = NO
  (found here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17921 and several other forums)

This did not work for me.  The only way I was able to remove the warnings was by either setting the GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = NO so the warnings are not shown or disabling the generation of the dsym file all together by setting DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = DWARF (and not  'DWARF with dSYM' File) .  The dsym file is important to me since it is used by all of the crash reporting software I use so disabling this process or suppressing the warnings by changing the build settings is not a solution for me.

---

Questions:
1. Is this a problem with my build settings or is there something wrong with the Facebook Audience Network SDKs and the other 3rd party SDKs I am using?
2. If I submit my app with this many warnings (200+) will it be approved?

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue. Facebook say they are aware of it and its not a high priority as it doesn't affect the app. I regressed back to 4.7.1 where the warning issue is no longer present.

I don't think it would be rejected but can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
Generate Debug Symbols = No
```

in `Build Settings`

Comment: Mentioned that dSYM's are important, so disabling them is not a solution.